# Salt Beacon monitor windows processes

Tags: salt-stack, beacon

I'm trying to use beacons for monitoring of windows processes and to fire event to salt-master event bus and catch it with wait for evert via salt runner which works.
Config as follow:

beacon.conf

```
beacons:
  ps:
    - processes:
        TiWorker.exe: stopped
        LogonUI.exe: running
    - interval: 60
```

wait-for-event

```
wait_for_TiWorker:
  salt.wait_for_event:
    - name: salt/beacon/*/ps/
    - id_list:
      - LKA5
    - timeout: 600
```

However, I have two problems:

1. I would like to monitor the state of two processes simultaneously and to fire event only if the two conditions are meet
2. How to add a custom tag to the event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I someone even looking for a solution:

I have created custom beacons for each of the processes with custom tag :)